# А это значит(,) у вас будет отличный заряд энергии на весь день

Tags: пунктуация

> А это значит(,) у вас будет отличный заряд энергии на весь день.

Нужно ли ставить запятую и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***А это значит,** у вас будет отличный заряд энергии на весь день.*

Да, запятая ставится.

Можно сравнить: *А значит, у вас будет отличный заряд энергии на весь день.* Здесь обособлено вводное слово, а в приведеноом примере  можно считать, что у нас  вводное предложение.

**Есть и другие варианты.**

При увеличенной паузе (в соответствующем контксте) можно поставить тире.

При объяснении мы можем считать, что это бессоюзное предложение, в таких предложениях (с изъяснительными отношениями) допускается постановка запятой.

Comment: А мне кажется лишним "это": обычно оно сочетается со "что" после запятой; в устной речи такое упрощение (не закончен обозначенный акцент на ранее сказанное) вполне допустимо, но на письме оно выглядит стилистически неубедительно (если это не транскрипция произнесенного). Отсюда неясности с запятой (или даже двоеточием).